# Why are React route urls not updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When i change the urls in my `App.js` file the component does not render anymore, so if I go to the new url I get an error as if the page does not exist but if I go to the old url it loads the navbar which is in the parent component but not the component in the route

*App.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import MainPage from "./mainpage";
import Details from "./Detail";
import SignUp from "../containers/Signup";
import AddItem from "./AddItem";
import Admin from "../containers/admin";
import CustomLayout from "../containers/Layout";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/Add-Item" component={AddItem} />
            <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route exact path="/post/:id" component={Details} />
          </Switch>
        </CustomLayout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*index.js*

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: I think you are missing the Switch element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Switch and change BrowserRouter to Router.

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={mainpage} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/Add-Item" component={AddItem} />
            <Route exact path="/admin" component={admin} />
            <Route exact path="/post/:id" component={Details} />
          </Switch >
        </CustomLayout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can try adding History; history.createBrowserHistory . . . to the router to see if it's working.

And then you can just to clickEvents to change path, so import history: the history.push('/path')

Comment: using history.push to the link worked, i don't really know why but it does, so Thanks.

Comment: no problem. just a way to overwrite <a> tags functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You missed Switch tag, below code will work fine:

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={mainpage} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/Add-Item" component={AddItem} />
            <Route exact path="/admin" component={admin} />
            <Route exact path="/post/:id" component={Details} />
          </Switch >
        </CustomLayout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tried it with Switch, did not work

Answer (score 1):

Add the Switch component like everyone is suggesting, get the components you're mounting to the Route are named and imported in Pascal case(Eg: MainPage). If these doesn't work can you paste the code dump of App.js file? (including imports)

**Update after code inspection**:
I changed one route URL to reproduce the issue, "/signup" to "/signupnew". You are right, after changing the URL, if you visit old one(which doesn't exist anymore) you will just see Layout wrapper(which is navbar and footer). This behavior is understandable as no matching route was found pointing to that path and no fallback route was specified to mount 404 component. this explains component not rendering on old path. On new URL/path I was able to render the component assigned to it.

**Change I Made in the code**

[image]

**Old Path**

[image]

**New Path**

[image]

Try to restart the react server and access new URL you changed in app.js file. Or if you changed the URL differently compared to what I did, Let me know.

Comment: i Edited the my post with the full App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stf-test-66109

Tried to reproduce similar situation and it works on my end. maybe its the components you are passing in the Routes and the way layout component is handling them. 

Would be able to debug more if you could use a platform like codesandbox to bringup a broken example.

Comment: i uploaded the whole project to github: https://github.com/xunsus/E-commerce-Test

Comment: edited my answer. let me know if I did something wrong in reproducing the issue.

Comment: the main issue is that i want to change `<Route exact path="/post/:id" component={Details} />` which only works if i do it like this `path="/:id"` (it was like this originaly). when i try `path="/post/:id"`  i get an error

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example about what i mean in the comment, just add Switch wrapping the routes

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about">
    <About />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Users />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: tried it with Switch, did not work